# C++ constructor and rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, rvalue

I was reading [this post](http://blog.aaronballman.com/2014/07/member-function-ref-qualifiers/). The code under attention is the following

```
struct S {
  void func() &;
  void func() &&;
};

S s1;
s1.func(); // OK, calls S::func() &
S().func(); // OK, calls S::func() &&
```

I think I understood what are the reference qualifiers. My question is more basic: what is `S()`? Is it a (copy) creator? Why is it an rvalue? It seems that in that blog and also in other places it is taken for granted. What am I missing?

Comment: The expression `S()` is a [*value initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) of a (temporary) `S` object.

Comment: `S()` is to `S myS` as `3` is to `int I(3)`; or more accurately as `int(3)` is to `int I(3)`. S() calls the constructor, but because you haven't put in a variable name, it is created as a temporary, or rvalue. [Sadly, `S myS()` would have made a better example, but due to the _most vexing parse_ it actually declares an extern function called myS that returns an object of type S].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally it's an explicit cast (functional notation). It creates a temporary object from the (possibly empty) list of arguments. And yes, it does so by doing overload resolution to pick the correct constructor to call. In this case, the default c'tor (which your compiler produces, on account of no other c'tor being declared).

More formally, the explicit cast is an expression whose result is a prvalue (pure rvalue). So when doing overload resolution to pick a member function to call, the rvalue qualified version is preferable.

I imagine the blog skimmed over it because that existed in C++ since time immemorial. And the post's intent was to introduce a new concept, assuming readers already know this about C++.

Answer (score 2):

`S()` creates a temporary object which is an rvalue. The object is constructed using default constructor. It is destroyed just after the full expression is evaluated.

More generally, one way to think about this syntax is: type name + arguments list passed to the constructor of the object.
In this case `S` is the type name and the empty parenthesis means there are no arguments for the constructor so the default constructor is chosen.

Comment: Ok but why? What it the creator invoked by `S()`?

Comment: @MaPo "creator"? You mean constructor? The default one.